# Should whitespace characters be allowed in a password?

Tags: security, string, passwords, whitespace

I've tried different sites/products and this seems to be split fairly evenly. Windows 7 and Gmail allow you to insert spaces in your password. Hotmail and Twitter do not.

While allowing spaces in a password increases the complexity of a password, it seems like many sites/programs do not allow them. Is there a good reason to allow/disallow spaces?

Comment: Spaces *might* make it easier to use a phrase such as in this xkcd comic: https://xkcd.com/936/ although you could just as easily use a phrase without spaces

Comment: Also there is now a related question here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32691/why-not-allow-spaces-in-a-password

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/262536/space-and-password-question) might be relevant.

I think that your observation is accurate: many web-based systems accept only alphanumerics and a subset of symbolic characters (say, `0-9A-Za-z/_-!`), but I think that this is simply historical convention. It may also be that programmers are used to the `<space>` character delimiting fields, rather than being found inside them.

There's also the issue of visibility: if you allow multiple *consecutive* spaces in a password, can the user easily count them? Might a system even collapse them into one (as unaided HTML would)? Can even a single space character be easily and quickly identified?

However, plenty of other types of systems do allow spaces in passwords. I'd probably still stray from them simply to help prevent user confusion (if people are indeed used to spaces in passwords being invalid, a password with a space in may be confusing to many), but there doesn't seem to be any technical reason not to allow them.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see would be usability for the user in terms of e.g. trailing spaces. Also if you start allowing non-visible characters like the space you might also start allowing all sorts of other non-visible characters like tabs and so on. Imho the disadvantages outweigh the benefits. To make a password really secure just increase the length and allow some special characters, numbers and letters and be case specific. With e.g. > 20 digits thats practically unbreakable at this stage (at least in terms of worth the effort..).

Comment: I'd dispute "practically unbreakable". 20 characters is ~160 bits (normally), and with a subset of characters allowed it contains less bits of information than that. That's not so much for a supercomputer to break in a wee while. It really depends on the use case, I guess.

Comment: 20 chars is still a challenge for a supercomputer. It all depends how short the "wee while" is in real terms!

Comment: I was talking about practically in terms of money. If you have a super computer to break a password and can run it for a few hours it better be a really important password..

Comment: Both space and tab are visible characters. Also if you use a password manager, as you should, then you would just copy-paste the password, and then anything goes. Any character is as good as any other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to test password strength--use google's own account password API:

https://www.google.com/accounts/RatePassword?Passwd=mypwd

Per your question about whitespace, I have entered a simple password with two characters and one whitespace "t t" . Google gave the password a rating of 3 out of 4.  If I do the same password, but remove the whitespace "tt" the rating received is 1 out of 4. By Google's rating standard, including whitespace improves the quality/strength of a password.

Comment: Improves the strength, but may break applications - white space is often used to delimit parameters.

Comment: The strength isn't entirely relevant to the question of whether you should allow them.