# Linux password manager trims trailing spaces in passwords

Tags: linux, configuration, passwords, whitespace, trim

I do quite agree with [those](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/32694/95649) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7240898/3719101) philosophies concerning whitespaces in passwords: they should be possible and responsibility left to user.

However linux native [`Password Store`](https://www.passwordstore.org/) utility, wrapping around `gpg`, does trim leading and trailing whitespaces:

```
$ pass insert test
Enter password for test:   wrapped   <Enter>
Retype password for test:   wrapped   <Enter>
$ pass test
wrapped|--------> well.. naked.
```

Is this just a customizable default behaviour?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the script obtains the passwords [by running the `read` builtin](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/src/password-store.sh#n443). By default, this builtin [scrubs leading and trailing whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689172/bash-read-line-does-not-read-leading-spaces).

This can be fixed by clearing the `IFS` environment variable, prior to using `read`.

As such, you will have to manually edit the shell script to clear `IFS` (you will also need to quote `$password` on line 447, too) if you want this to work.

Comment: Neat analyze. Thanks :) If you were me, would you rather create a custom patch or file this as a bug to [`pass`](https://www.passwordstore.org/)? Maybe modifying source this way can have unexpected repercussions..

Comment: Why not both? Fix it in your local copy then send a push request to the project with the changes you've made.

Comment: Neat. I will :)

Comment: Well, my e-mails to [`pass`](https://lists.zx2c4.com/mailman/listinfo/password-store) seem completely ignored, even though their mailing list seems active.. maybe I've missed something :(