# Trimming passwords, is that wrong?

Tags: c#

I had a issue that the password for a new record was not blank, it was one empty space. So the first thing came to mind is to call `Trim()` where I load or save passwords, so won't have that blank space issue anymore. But I wanted to get your opinion on whether it would be a wrong thing to do or not?

Comment: How is the user supposed to know his password if you trim his ending space that he deliberately put in there?

Comment: people have passwords with space in the beginning or end, so no need to trim it, also don't store password in plan text.

Comment: I vote for reopen. Although the OP asked for opinions, this question is about a best practice, really.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't be storing passwords in plain text.

Comment: To elaborate on this, use PBKDF2, bcrypt, or scrypt (with salt) with a reasonable workload. Then you won't have "problems" like this.

Comment: True, but it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

It is wrong, because you're not letting the user know that the password that is being stored is different from what he/she entered... You can have a server side check using [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and as stated in the other answer, you shouldn't store it in plain text

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would recommend you don't allow such short passwords in any case.

Also, in my experience leading & trailing spaces on passwords are almost always unintended by the user. However, if you require password entry twice, it is unlikely a user will accidentally pad their intended password twice (unless that use cut/paste to fill it out). However, since this is also a common practice, I always trim leading/trailing blanks from passwords -- **internal** spaces should be preserved though.

ADDED

Having read that other say trimming is bad, I still say they are wrong. If you always trim and using always pads, their password will always work -- and they will not know that the stored password is not an exact match -- Of course, as you should never store a "password" just a one-way hash of the result, there is really know way to know what the password is anyway, just whether or not it hashes to the correct hash value.

Answer (score 1):

Space is a valid character for passwords. So you should not trim it.

Besides [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be used instead of 'String' class for storing passwords.

Comment: Google does trim passwords... Whether it's wrong or not

Comment: Agreed but that is not a widely used standard.  You cannot rely on space not being a password char. Some authentication system allow it, some does not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475071/should-whitespace-characters-be-allowed-in-a-password

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you put a minimum character limit or validation on the password validation, and not trim.

Answer (score 1):

The correct behavior (at least one of the best practices) is to try to encrypt and then hash passwords. Encrypting even the most simple password, even a simple whitespace would create a non-whitespace string.

Here's a simple code to do that:

```
public static string Hash(this string text)
{
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = algorithm = MD5.Create(); ;
    // Adding something (salt) to text to make it harder to guess
    text += "some-salt";
    //return algorithm.ComputeHash(text.ToBytes()).GetString().ToBase64();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)));
}
```

Call this function on a whitespace, and the result is:

```
var result = " ".Hash();
// Xd�m���SJ�l|r�Z*
```